# Poisson Distribution Greater than problem

Tags: probability

A company manufactures long continuous lengths of computer network
cable. The manufacturing process is not perfect, and sometimes faults
are present in the cables. Faults occur along the cables according to
a Poisson process, so that on average 1 fault occurs in 1000 metres of
cable.
Suppose you buy 400 metres of cable from the manufacturer in order to
connect 40 computers to a server, each by 10 metres of cable.

**What is the probability that there are two or more faults?**

I tried to find 1- {Pr(x=0)+pr(x=1)} but I arrived at a different solution to the past paper solution. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: So reason enough to include your calculations. Where are they?

Comment: λ = 1/1000

pr(x=0) = ((1/1000)^0)/0! * e^(-1/1000) = 0.999 but this is for faults per metre. so for faults in 400 metres = 0.999^400 = 0.67

Comment: Pr (x=1) = (e^-(1/1000))/1000 = 0.000999 again this is faults for 1metre. so for faults in 400m = 0.000999^400 = 0

therefore Pr(x=0)+Pr(x=1) = 0.67

so Pr(x> or equal to 2) = 1- 0.67 = 0.33

however the book says the solution is 0.0616

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If faults occur they will occur in the individual 10 metre lengths. The expected number of faults per 10 metre length is $\lambda=\frac {10}{1000}=0.01$
The probability of a faulty commection is, assuming Poisson, $$p=1-e^{-0.01}$$ since more than one fault could occur in any 10 metre section.
Now use the Binomial distribution with $n=40$ and the value of $p$ found.
You then need to find $1-p(X=0\cup 1)$

Answer (score 0):

I found a small sample problem in Mathematica, that resembles yours. Faults occur at a rate of 1 per 1000 meter of cable. $\lambda =\frac{1}{1000}$
If you were to purchase 400 meters, the probability of 1 or less faults within that 400 m of cable is $\frac{5}{e^4}$ or 0.091578 %.